# Unable to fit model using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a simple model using keras. when I want to fit my model, I face with an error. The error is:

TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix that?

```
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000,784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000,784)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

#Normalize
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

#convert label to one hot
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

myModel = Sequential()
myModel.add(Dense(500, activation='relu',input_shape=(784,)))
myModel.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
myModel.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

myModel.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001),loss=categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])

network_history = myModel.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=2)
```

and this is the error:

```
network_history = myModel.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=(128))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Parisima\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13876/4252018919.py", line 1, in <module>
    network_history = myModel.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=(128))

  File "C:\Users\Parisima\anaconda3\envs\tf_envs\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\Users\Parisima\anaconda3\envs\tf_envs\lib\typing.py", line 1083, in _no_init
    raise TypeError('Protocols cannot be instantiated')

TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated
```

Comment: Which version of python/tensorflow are you using?

Comment: It seems this is the issue with `Python 3.9.7`. Please upgrade or downgrade python version to Python>3.9 or Python 3.8 if you are using Python 3.9. Please check this similar [issue](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5140) here.